# Listing variable types using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to transfer most of my favourite R commands to `tidyverse`. And one of the first things I usually check after importing data is the formatting of each variable, for example:

```
data(cars)
sapply(cars, class)

#    speed      dist 
# "numeric" "numeric"
```

becomes:

```
library(tidyverse)
exam.table %>%
   sapply(class)

#    speed      dist 
# "numeric" "numeric"
```

So how would you transpose this in `tidyverse`? The old version would be:

```
t(t(sapply(cars,class)))

#          [,1]     
#    speed "numeric"
#    dist  "numeric"
```

Comment: I disagree that using a pipe with `sapply` is any more “tidyversey” than writing it as a function call. First off, the pipe isn’t exclusive to the tidyverse, it existed independent and before the tidyverse. Secondly, `sapply` is very much a base R function, there’s nothing tidyversey about it. The point of using tidyverse functions is to avoid pitfalls from base R functions, and `sapply` has pitfalls galore.

Comment: Sorry, I've got used to call everything using the `tidyverse` package and pipe connotation `tidyverse` for simplicity. My students instantly combust if I refer to each element by the correct package name (i.e. `dplyr`, `gglot2`, `magrittr` etc.). Yes, there's nothing wrong with base R commands, but again my students want to do as much as possible with pipes (doh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cars %>% sapply(class) %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column("col")

    col       .
1 speed numeric
2  dist numeric
```

Or

```
cars %>% sapply(class) %>% as.data.frame()
            .
speed numeric
dist  numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

A very "tidyversic" prose might be:

```
cars %>% map_df(class) %>% t()
      [,1]     
speed "numeric"
dist  "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

The “tidyverse” equivalent of `sapply` is the [`purrr::map` family of functions](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html). In your case, `map_chr`:

```
map_chr(df, class)
```

If you want the result in a data.frame, just wrap it inside a `tibble`:

```
tibble(cols = names(cars), class = map_chr(cars, class))
```

… of course you could pipeline notation for this, as well:

```
cars %>% {tibble(col = names(.), class = map_chr(., class))}
```

Or

```
cars %>% map_chr(class) %>% tibble(col = names(.), class = .)
```